# Distribute Item to Multiple Stores as per Allocated Quantity to Gown SP

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have Tables Lets Say,

```
TABLEA

Id  TotalQty  PropsedAmount  AllocatedAmount

TABLEB

TableAID TableBID  MemberCount Commodity TotalQty
```

Question:

For TableB

`Commodity: 5 Member : 3 TotalQty: 15`

But in `TableA`
TotalQty Allocated to the specific Commodity is `14`

then how can I reallocate the Commodity based on `TableA` (Considering this to be final)

Best Possible Example as I do Not have data as well :) :

Case 1

There are 100 students in a class and Class teacher said everyone we will give 1 apple to every student

case 2

Principle said we only had 90 apples so distribute them accordingly

case 3

Now every student should get .9 apple instead of 1

Comment: Add dummy data and show expected output.

Comment: "Reallocate the commodity based on TableA" . Not getting this clearly. do you want to update the commodity in tableB with TableA?

Comment: @Justcode tried my best bro

Comment: What I got is, you need to distribute the qty among the members. and what is the criteria to do this?

Comment: yes lot of criteria but right now what i have is total qty and then student count

Comment: Create sample data and expected output in Excel. --- Copy to http://www.sensefulsolutions.com/2010/10/format-text-as-table.html --- Paste result into your question. --- Profit.